# Using StructureMap to add registries in 2 assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I have 2 projects - UI and Core. I have StructureMap set up in my Core project like so:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg => cfg.Scan(scanner =>
{
    scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
    scanner.LookForRegistries();
}));
```

and I have a Registry set up which which allows me to use IoC on my repositories:

```
public class CoreRegistry : Registry
{
    public CoreRegistry()
    {
        Scan(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
            cfg.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    }
}
```

I am initializing this in global.asax. All of this configuration is black-boxed away in Core and everything works great.

However, now I'd like to use StructureMap for IoC in my UI project. Is it possible to add more to the configuration after it's already been configured? I'd hate to have to unravel everything to get my UI elements to register.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same strategy to register ui objects.  You can send reference to UI assembly into ` method that looking for registries in Core dll. And scan UI assembly for registires as well:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg => cfg.Scan(scanner =>
{
    scanner.TheCallingAssembly();
    scanner.Assembly(assembly);
    scanner.LookForRegistries();
}));
```

And than you can as usual declare registries in UI project. Also you can add any number of registries in any time.